# Do I allocate the array after my main frame or before

Tags: c

I am trying to write this code but I keep getting this error.

> error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘float[(long unsigned int)(number_of_elements)]’ from type ‘float *’

Ive tried everything and Im just stumped.

```
list1_input_value =
      (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * number_of_elements);
if (list1_input_value == (float*)NULL) {
    printf("ERROR: the attempt to allocate array failed.\n");
    exit(program_failure_code);
} /*  if (list1_input_value == (float*)NULL) */
else
list1_input_value = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) *
number_of_elements);
if (list2_input_value == (float*)NULL) {
    printf("ERROR: the attempt to allocate array failed.\n");
    exit(program_failure_code);
} /*  if (list2_input_value == (float*)NULL) */
```

Comment: Looks like `C` (or, may be, `C++`), not `C#`

Comment: First it's not C# so tagging is incorrect, second you didn't provide the type of `list1_input_value` so it's unclear where exactly it fails and also I believe second allocation is supposed to be used with `list2_input_value`, not `list1_input_value`.

Comment: sorry it is c++. Also here   int number_of_elements;
   float* list1_input_values = (float*)NULL;
   float* list2_input_values = (float*)NULL;
   float list1_input_value[number_of_elements];
   float list2_input_value[number_of_elements];

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the new information.

Comment: Anyway, @ElayM was right in their answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're **probably** trying to assign to an array. That's not possible.

You don't need to allocate memory for an array, it already has an address and a size. You can't assign it a new address, even if it's the same size as the array (address).

In order to manually allocate memory for `list1_input_value` you need to declare it as a pointer `float * list1_input_value` rather than an array `float list1_input_value[number_of_elements]` and then you would be able to allocate memory for it.